# NSTabView Item adding an Icon in TabViewItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstabview

I subclassed NSTabView and added 5 TabViewItem, now i wanted to add an Icon along with the title  in the NSTabViewItem, 
Can anyone suggest me how to start, i am not getting any documentation except,

```
- (void)drawLabel:(BOOL)shouldTruncateLabel inRect:(NSRect)tabRect
```

Does that mean, if i override this method, i need to draw Icon and string my own,

For setting up the title , i am using following method,

```
[pTabViewItem setLabel:pLabelTitle];
```

Kind Regards
Rohan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never Mind, 
Following Code works for me,

```
- (void)drawLabel:(BOOL)shouldTruncateLabel inRect:(NSRect)tabRect{

    // do we have an image to draw
    NSImage *pImage = [pDelegate imageForCell];

    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] saveGraphicsState];
    NSAffineTransform* xform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
    [xform translateXBy:0.0 yBy: tabRect.size.height];
    [xform scaleXBy:1.0 yBy:-1.0];
    [xform concat]; 


    CGFloat x_Offset =0;
    if(pImage){
        [pImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(tabRect.origin.x-8,-6,16, 16)fromRect:NSZeroRect
                 operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
                  fraction:1.0];
        x_Offset =  16;
    }
     [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] restoreGraphicsState];

    [super drawLabel:shouldTruncateLabel inRect:tabRect];
}
```

Why transformation:
Image was showing inverted, so i need to transform,

Why offset: 
Even after transformation, i need to adjust, the position so that it looks just before the title,

and guys, i while setting the title,

append a Space, so title will not overlap the image, i know this is ugly approach, but couldn’t get any other quick way to do it, if i draw the text myself then i need to take care of truncating also,

Thanks to those who looked at questions and answer
Kind Regards
Rohan